# filtering out other files, respecting renames

Tags: git, blob, git-filter-branch

I've got a repository that effectively contains a bunch of different modules.  I'd like to split it out into separate repositories, keeping the version history of the files in those repositories.

A simple approach to this problem would just involve cloning the repo and then doing something like

```
git filter-branch \
    --tree-filter $'find -type f \
                    | grep -vF <(echo "file1\nfile2\n...") -- --all \
                    | xargs rm' --prune-empty -- --all
```

but that will (assuming that my untested script was written correctly) delete all files with the given **names**.

What I *really* want to do is to walk the commit history, finding and deleting files which have not *become* any of those files.  So if `file_a` was renamed to `file_b` 14 commits ago, and (the current) `file_b` is supposed to be part of this repo, those old `file_a`'s should be kept in the repo as well.

This should extend in both directions; i.e. if there is another branch in which `file_a` was never renamed, it should really —err, actually that's a bit ambiguous.  The definition of `file_a` is dependent on a particular branch.  What I want (I think..) is to specify a set of blobs, e.g. `HEAD:file_b`, and have the filter eliminate all blobs that are not part of the history of one of those blobs.

Comment: I guess your separate modules aren't in separate directories, huh? That's unfortunate. I'll give this a little thought - sounds pretty tricky.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately not.  It started out as just a quick place to put a few functions that I commonly use, but some of those functions are growing complex enough to be modules of their own.